Changing local Chat backup to Google Drive backup for WhatsApp
Earlier Chat backup of WhatsApp was local. Now I want to change local Chat backup to Google Drive backup. I am not able to change. Whenever I click Chat backup, it starts doing local backup.
I am using cloned WhatsApp.
Please let me know, how to do it?

Is your device already linked to a Google account? Have you selected the Google Account in Settings - Chats - Chats backup - Google Account?

Yes, Google account and Google Drive is active and logged in in the device.
